# Unable to open the URL into new tab even using target ="_blank"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm unable to open the URL into new tab. Kindly help.

Javascript :

```js
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
    'transport': 'beacon',
    'hitCallback': function() {
      document.location = url;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa-twitter" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://twitter.com/'); return false;">Twitter</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove `return false;` from `onclick`

Comment: thanks @NebojsaNebojsa but there is a new tab opening but the homepage is also redirected to twitter. :(

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting `return false;` in `onclick` and using `document.location`.

Try to change `document.location` to `window.open` function

JavaScript

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
    'transport': 'beacon',
    'hitCallback': function() {
      window.open(url);
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa-twitter" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://twitter.com/'); return false;"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a>
```

Comment: _"ReferenceError: ga is not defined"_

Comment: @JamesDouglas you need to include the google analytics script file inorder to recognse the ga function.  I think I should remove the snippet and make it to a code block because window.open will also get blocked by stacksnippet

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure if it was just a typo on the OP's part, but I suppose that's fine.

Comment: OP didn't included the external js file. That's why it is undefined. Thanks for the comment. since Snippet block window.open, I converted it into code.